# How to Create a Custom Listview without extending List Activity?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I Want to Create a List View with a Custom layout which will contain A image and text

But all the tutorials i find all extend List Activity but i cant extend List Activity because i need to add buttons and other things to the layout.
I need to use the ListView using a custom item layout

any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not bound to use `ListActivity` in order to have a `ListView` in your layout. All the samples using `ListActivity` are there because people are lazy ;)

So just use a regular `Activity` and then you simply have to add the `ListView` to the layout you are setting as content view. This could look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/somethingButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do something" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/elseButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do something else" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in like any other `Activity` in your `OnCreate` method you do:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.myLayout); // myLayout.axml

var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
listView.Adapter = new MyAdapter(context, itemsSource);

var somethingButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.somethingButton);
var elseButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.elseButton);

... more code ...
```

`ListView` is just a layout just like any other, so there is nothing magic about it. `MyAdapter` in this sample is ofcourse something you implement, which takes your data and presents it in the desired image and text layout.

For more information about `ListView` and `Adapter` please [refer to the excellent documentation which Xamarin provides](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/).